# Run SBT command from task

Tags: scala, sbt

Is it possible to run an SBT command (that's defined in my build.sbt) from a task (that's also defined in my build.sbt) ?

Alternatively can I add a command as a dependency to a task (ie: I want to run a command before I compile).

Answer (score 3):

```
Command.process("you_command", state.value)
```

use `Command.process` to call your custom `command`

Answer (score 3):

In sbt 1.0 `Command.process` has been dropped.
Use insertion or appending to add command to state as below:

```
  val insertCommand: State => State =
    (state: State) =>
      state.copy(remainingCommands = Exec("some-command", None) +: state.remainingCommands)
```

see http://www.scala-sbt.org/1.0/docs/Build-State.html

Answer (score 2):

`Command.process("you_command", state.value)`

The `process` method is back from version 1.2.0.
But, it won't change the whole state just run the command and return a new state.